# Error after upgrading to Capacitor v3 package com.getcapacitor.annotation does not exist

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

My angular ionic application was working fine on Android platform before updating capaitor to version 3.
After I update to Version3 I got this error whe I try to run my app on the emulator from Android studio

C:\ionic\dhaman-customer-service\node_modules@capacitor\storage\android\src\main\java\com\capacitorjs\plugins\storage\StoragePlugin.java:8: error: package com.getcapacitor.annotation does not exist
import com.getcapacitor.annotation.CapacitorPlugin;
^
I am using Storage plugin in my application

The following is the out put of npx cap doctor command
Latest Dependencies:

@capacitor/cli: 2.4.7
@capacitor/core: 2.4.7
@capacitor/android: 2.4.7
@capacitor/ios: 2.4.7

Installed Dependencies:

@capacitor/ios: not installed
@capacitor/cli: 3.0.0-rc.0
@capacitor/android: 2.4.7
@capacitor/core: 3.0.0-rc.0

[success] Android looking great!

this is acreen shot
[image]

Answer (score 6):

problem fixed after Upgrading capacitor/android to version 3 beta

npm install @capacitor/android@3.0.0-beta.3

Answer (score 1):

Install
npm install @capacitor/android

this will install the latest public version, check https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capacitor/android?activeTab=versions

Answer (score 0):

To add more to the question and answer, I was getting error after upgrading to Ionic 7: **com.getcapacitor.util.InternalUtils** not found. I just did `npm install @capacitor/android@latest` and its all cool.

Capacitr 4.8
Ionic 7,
Gradle 7.2

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by installing the same versions of the ionic dependencies, for example if I have installed "@capacitor/cli": "4.1.0" the rest must also have the same version "@capacitor/cli": "4.1.0" ,
"@capacitor/core": "4.1.0",
"@capacitor/ios": "4.1.0",